# How can i add iframe in my master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I want to add iframe in my master page. suppose i ll refer this master page to other aspx page, the content  of the contentplaceholder always display in iframe . Please help me to do this ..

This is my master page contenplace holder code:

```
  <div class="main">

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>
```

please help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to VinayC, you don't want a Master page. You want a container page, old school HTML or another aspx, that will hold your iFrame. As VinayC pointed out, a master page is just a template, not an actual page that gets served. It's a layout template, nothing more.

If we're misunderstanding your intent and you need to inject an iFrame into a page, here's a bit of javascript that will do that:

```
function InsertIFrame(path) {                           
                                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                                iframe.src = path;
                                document.body.appendChild(iframe);                                
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably MasterPage/ContentPage does not work the way you are thinking. ASP.NET simply merges the content of both to produce the output. Master-page is just a layout that will be used while displaying the content page - the master page itself is not a navigable content.

From what you are describing, you probably don't need master page. What you need is a normal page that will have your basic layout along with an iframe whose source you can set to start-page. Once loaded, all the navigation will happen in the iframe giving you what you want.

Comment: I just using a single master page for all pages am having more forms . So i want to show that content in iframe...